# Converting for loop from matlab to python

Tags: matlab, python, numpy

I am converting some MATLAB code in to python and have the encountered the error "ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 for ig in range(nbas):
----> 2     psi[:,ig] = np.polyval(np.array(pp[ig,:ig]),nodes)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (56,1) into shape (56)
" I cannot find the issue with following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as scl

##basis parameters (nbas<ngrid+1)
nbas = 54 #Basis set size in one dimension
ngrid = 56 #quadrature size

#Gauss-Hermite-Quadrature
#Hermite matrix
def hermipol(n):
    p = np.zeros((n+1,n+1))
    p[0][0] = 1
    if n == 0:
        p = np.array([[1,0],[2,0]], dtype = float)
    if n > 0:
        p[1][range(0,2)] = np.array([2,0])
        if n >=1:
            for k in range(2,n+1):
                p[k][range(n)] = 2*p[k-1][range(0,n)]
                p[k][range(2,n+1)] += -2*(k-1)*p[k-2][range(0,n-1)]
    for i in range(0,n+1):
        p[i,:] /= np.sqrt(np.sqrt(np.pi)*2**(i)*scl.factorial(i))

    return(p)
#Generation Gauss-Hermite Quadrature nodes and weights
def ghquad(n):
    return(np.polynomial.hermite.hermgauss(n))
[nodes,weights]  = ghquad(ngrid)

pp = hermipol(ngrid)


#Evaluation and store psi_i()(x,y)_k)
nodes = np.array([nodes]).T
weights = np.array([weights]).T
print(weights)
print(nodes)
np.shape(nodes)
psi = np.zeros((ngrid,nbas))
np.shape(psi)

for ig in range(nbas):
    psi[:,ig] = np.polyval(np.array(pp[ig,:ig]),nodes)
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post is better suited for Stackoverflow I think.
Anyway you can simply solve your problem by changing `psi[:,ig]`to `psi[:,ig:ig+1]`. Then the left-hand side is truly a nx1 matrix, not just a vector of size n.

Or you can remove the line `nodes = np.array([nodes]).T` which is useless here, and causes Numpy to transform the array "nodes" (size n), into a 1xn array. Then the original `psi[:,ig]` works.

This kind of shape issue should easily be debugged by hand though !

Comment: Solved, thanks for the response! when I post questions in the future I will use the over.